# Image goes over border of listview when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll, imageview

I've created several items in a list view. Each item in the listview is comprised of a custom adapter with a two row table. I have images and texts in the rows of the adapter table. When I scroll the list view, the contents of each row go over the border of the list view.  This is driving my OCD bonkers. Thanks in advance.

I have a perfect picture of this and it won't let me to post it.

New to all of this so thanks for the patience.

-Dave

posting code per request:

Shape.xml, defines border for the list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" 
    android:color="@color/white_text">

    <solid 
        android:color="@color/all_white"/>

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/border_color" />


</shape>
```

game table that defines each list entry

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/awayLogo"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/awayName"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/awayScore"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/awayTime"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/homeLogo"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homeName"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homeScore"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homeTime"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: If you can't post the image, you should post your code.

Comment: The image is showing up fine, the problem is that it appears on top of the border for the list view as i scroll through the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post the xml that actually shows the `@drawable/shape` as your background, but I can make a suggestion.

- Add another layout that wraps the listview.
- Set the background of the wrapper layout to be `@drawable/shape`.
- Set `android:padding="2dp"` on the wrapper layout.

Then the listview will be inset by the amount of the stroke width of the shape, and it shouldn't display on top of your shape border.